# How to execute a cron expression for every 2.5 hours?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cron, cronexpression

We are using quartz scheduler for scheduling and I have a requirement where I need to execute a job for every 2.5 hours. Please build a cron expression for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Please build a cron expression for this."*  Please do your own work or show some effort and ask a specific question.

Comment: Not a real question, vote to close

Comment: If you can build it build it and show me.. You cant do that and there is no right to degrade others you lol............ Andrew Thompson

Comment: If you cant solve some question you people post not a real question and close the question. If you dont understand ask people to explain the question more clearly... You dont know the answer so you close the question thats what I unsderstand...MadProgrammer

Comment: Its a challenge for you Mr. Andrew Thompson you answer this question I agree your reputation in this site is worthable. I you cant your reputation is such a shit on the road...........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that you have you have to execute the script at the following timings
0.00, 2.30,5.00,7.30,10.00,12.30,15.00,17.30,20.00,22.30

I am not sure whether you can write this in a single cron command. You can follow the below procedure.

You can split this into two halves.
0.00,5.00,10.00,15.00,20.00  and

2.30,7.30,12.30,17.30,22.30
You can add 2 entries in cron 
0  */5  *  *  * CMD

and
30  2,7,12,17,22  *  *  * CMD

Hope this helps you..

Comment: I think this is a wrong answer anyway: it is still executing for every 2 hours. Scheduled time will be: 0:30, 2:30, 4:30, 6:30 ....

Comment: yup You are correct... this is what I understood from his question.

Comment: I believe OP is asking for "every 2 and a half hour", that means, "every 2.5 hour", which means something like : 0:00, 2:30, 5:00, 7:30...

Comment: Oh okay. I mis interpreted the question..

Comment: Thanks for your understanding.......Adrian Shum. If possible please help me........

Comment: @Rocky: What have you tried? Show us what you tried, instead of just blaming other for telling you about your question is not asked appropriately.  Back to your question, two way u can choose: 2 cron expression, or switch to other scheduling method instead of using cron

Comment: Since this question is closed. I have edited my above answer.

Comment: @Rocky - I have edited the answer. Please check whether it helps you..

Comment: +1 for putting up a right answer after getting it wrong in the first attempt

Comment: There is an argument missing.

0 */5 * * *  --> 0 */5 * * * ? |||||
30 2,7,12,17,22 * * * --> 30 2,7,12,17,22 * * * ?

Cause CronExpression require 6 fields. See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm#insertedID0